# iPhone4, iOS5 Networked, multiplayer Augmented reality (AR/VR) game. Where to start?

Tags: gps, ios5, augmented-reality, iphone-4, core-motion

I'm working on a pretty complicated app right now, but I just got a really good, niche market idea for an AR game for iPhone. I would love to get some preliminary research done on whether or not it is worth the effort. I got a few (about 4 days) in which to code this. Is this a realistic timeline for what I'm trying to accomplish?

While I'm pretty familiar with the CMDeviceMotion, and can get location updates from GPS, there are 4 features that I think may take a colossal amount of work:

1) Working with camera in real time to draw augmented reality controls. Are there any good tutorials on how to overlay a view on top of a live camera feed?

2)Making the app work when GPS reception is spotty. It seems that some apps know how to keep updating the location based on accelerometer/gyroscope from the last known location. Where would I start on this front?

3)The networking component. I'm very new to multiplayer games. I got a website that can run PHP. Should I abandon my networking idea until I get a web server? Or is there some way I can run this in P2P over 3G without a base station?

4)Google maps integration for fast updates. Does this take a lot of effort?

I'm sorry if any of these questions are too broad and vague. I'm very excited about this idea, but would like to know what I'm dealing with before spending time on the app and realizing that I'm dealing with a monumental task!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are dealing with a monumental task (especially the multiplayer part, where you'll encounter issues like lag/timing).

For the augmented reality part of your project, you can take a look at mixare augmented reality engine. It's free and open source software and the code is available on github: https://github.com/mixare/ 
Be aware that if you base your code upon mixare, you'll have to release your app under the same GPLv3 license as mixare.

Good luck for your project!

HTH,
Daniele

Comment: Daniele, thank you for the heads up! I checked out your videos, and they are very much like what I'm trying to accomplish, except on a smaller scale. I see that you are using Android, while I hope to get this project done on iPhone. It appears to me that you do not have a gyroscope on your android, otherwise the rotation would be a lot smoother. The google I/O 2011 had some videos on using a gyroscope enabled android, and it's really impressive for AR. Networking really concerns me in this case, full bi-directional communication may really take a toll on most 3G networks.

Comment: There is an iPhone version as well (that uses the gyroscope). I am not the developer of it though but check out the code on github! :) As for the gyro on android, I prefer not to release any code based on it until I have a phone (with gyro) on which I can test it. :)